# PHP Warning: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable using xampp

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php program using xampp but it shows the following error:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable.

The part of code where the error is being shown is given below:

```
    if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) {
        curl_close($resource);
    } else {
        // Remove all callback functions as they can hold onto references
        // and are not cleaned up by curl_reset. Using curl_setopt_array
        // does not work for some reason, so removing each one
        // individually.
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, null);
        curl_reset($resource);
        $this->handles[] = $resource;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$this->handles` initialised to?

Comment: You have to pass an array in `count` function

Answer (score 1):

First check if $this->handles is a array or object like this:

```
if(is_array($this->handles) || is_object($this->handles))
{
        if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) {
        curl_close($resource);
    } else {
        // Remove all callback functions as they can hold onto references
        // and are not cleaned up by curl_reset. Using curl_setopt_array
        // does not work for some reason, so removing each one
        // individually.
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, null);
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, null);
        curl_reset($resource);
        $this->handles[] = $resource;
    }
}
else
{
    echo $this->handles." isn't a array or object";
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not an array or object. This is not my own code, i just cloned a repo and ran the code. So, am not completely sure about the code. This is the repo:
https://github.com/unshift/goutte-php-scraper-boilerplate

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have everything 'installed'  to use curl ? maybe curl just cant 'run', thats why its empty.

Answer (score 0):

the `count()` method in **php >= 7.2**, if it receives invalid values, null and false, it will send the following error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in … on line..
```

This item in **php8**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument # 1 ($var) must be of type Countable...
```

As a result, before checking with the `count()` method, you can first check that the countable types are not invalid. (For example, according to your needs, use the `empty()` method before that or give an `empty array value` or ... ) or use methods such as `is_array` or `is_object` or ...

> 7.2.0 count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the value parameter.